# how to exclude from strip tag function by specific class

Tags: php, html, regex, strip-tags

i want to strip tag a string and exclude an a tag by specific class Name.

have this input :

```
<p><a class="className">Text</a></p>
```

want this output:

```
<a class="className">Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strip_tags(STRING, ALLOW TAG);

<?php
$text = '<p><a class="className">Text</a></p>';
echo strip_tags($text, "<a>");
?>
```